# How can re-bootstrap angular app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have 2 type pages

1. Grid with posts
2. post details page (with related posts)

when click to post on first page i show modal view and get content from ajax request, after that run `angular.bootstrap`. It is ok, it works

i have a problem on second page, because i run `angular.bootstrap` when page loads, for exact post, and when want to "re-bootstrap" angular then click to related post (showing with modal), get a problem, cause already have a ng-app, but i can't remove DOM for the exact post.

do you have any suggestion about this thing ?

Comment: DId you find the way to do it?

Comment: If remember right - no.

Comment: The answer to this is provided in <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43234416/resetting-angular-2-app>

Comment: @Shubham this question was about angular 1.